# JavaFX installation on IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I need JavaFX for a university work. I followed every tutorial, doc, etc, but I have this error:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found VM
>   Options:
>   --module-path \Java\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib
>   --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

It works with JDK 11, but not with JDK 14.

Comment: Dont khow why wih JDK 11 it works.... but with JDK 14 no

Comment: Did you try to specify the absolute directory for the `--module-path`?

Comment: Yes, the Path is correct, idk why with JDK11 works but with JDK 14 it dosent

Comment: Try reinstalling JavaFX SDK for JDK 14, it may be invalid or incomplete.